# Insert unique values from PHP array into SQL table

Tags: php, sql, insert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

There is SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MyTable` (
  `id` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MyVar` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

And there are two PHP arrays `arr1[]=array("abc","bcd")` and `arr2[]=array("abc","cde")`.

Let's say I have saved arr1[] values to SQL table. Now let's suppose I need to save arr2[] values to the same SQL table. Which SQL INSERT query do I need to write in order to avoid duplicate saving of "abc" entry? The result must be:

```
MyTable:
1  |  abc
2  |  bcd
3  |  cde
```

**but NOT:**

```
MyTable:
1  |  abc
2  |  bcd
3  |  abc
4  |  cde
```

UPDATE:
Maybe the MyTable should be created/defined in such a way that duplicate entries are ignored?

Comment: Set a unique constraint for your MyVar column. So trying to insert a value which already exists will not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` + rest of the query

Comment: Which duplicate (merging / intersecting arrays) or (inserting stuff that doesn't exist already) or both depends on the details but I think there's enough material there to get you to a good solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `MyVar` as `UNIQUE` in your table.

Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MyTable` (
  `id` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MyVar` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `myvaridx` (`MyVar`)
);
```

or, if you're unable to recreate the table, alter it using

```
ALTER TABLE `request`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `myvaridx` (`MyVar`)
```

Answer (score 6):

There are 3 possible solutions: using `INSERT IGNORE`, `REPLACE`, or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Check this [article](http://bogdan.org.ua/2007/10/18/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-syntax.html).

You can also in memory [intersect array-s](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) and then insert just unique values if that solution fits for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL for such task would be wasteful.

I suggest to use using the "array_merge" function to merge the arrays and then "array_unique" function to handle the duplication.

Then insert the unique values to the database.